# Why are some 3D buildings more detailed than others in iOS's Maps app?

Tags: ios, graphics, maps

In iOS's Maps app, some 3D rendered buildings have ample details and colors, such as the San Francisco Golden Gate bridge or the details of the Oracle Park:

[image]

[image]

However, some other buildings have less details or colors, such as the Eiffel Tower:

[image]

What is the reason behind this inconsistency?
Do buildings have to partner with Apple to be represented more favorably on the Maps app, or are the more detailed buildings part of an open source library that Apple picks from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple are still working on more. They're custom-designed and take time.

> hundreds of custom-designed landmarks like Coit Tower in San Francisco, Dodger Stadium in LA, the Statue of Liberty in NYC, and the Royal Albert Hall in London, with more to come.

https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2021/09/apple-maps-introduces-new-ways-to-explore-major-cities-in-3d/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It still doesn’t clarify what the decision process behind it is, if it’s a partnership type of situation… like why is the San Francisco carousel well designed but not the Eiffel Tower (the most visited monument in the world)? Just trying to understand the logic. If they are commercial partnerships, it’s not well explained

Comment: Ps I get a 403 forbidden error when I click your link